# Psych Library polychoric Function Error "You have more than 8 categories for your items, polychoric is probably not needed"

Tags: r, psych

I'm new to R and running into an error with the `polychoric` function in the `psych` package. I'm attempting to store the polychoric correlation matrix in a data frame from using the following syntax:

`RPOL36 <- polychoric(norm.kdqol36,smooth=TRUE)`

where `norm.kdqol36` is a data frame with vectors of ordered variables, each with 5 levels (0, 25, 50, 75, 100). Here is an example:

`0    25    50    75   100 
11962 19953  4987 12998  8261`

Despite each variable having 5 levels, I get this error:

> Error in polychoric(norm.kdqol36, smooth = TRUE) :    You have more
>   than 8 categories for your items, polychoric is probably not  needed

Could there be a formatting issue causing the `polychoric` function to read my variables as having more than 5 categories?

Comment: Including a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in your question will increase your chances of getting an answer.

Answer (score 2):

polychoric assumes categorical data with fewer than 8 or so categories  However, your data meet this assumption.  The short term fix is to recode your 0,25,50,75,100 data into 0,1,2,3,4  (i.e. divide by 25).
I have just fixed this problem so the next release of psych (1.8.1) will do this recoding for you.